# How to deny WCF entities to show in some endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, endpoint

i have a wcf service with 3 endpoints and i have within the service entities decorated with DataContract and DataMember.

my question is, is it possible to deny the datacontractserializer to do his job in some endpoints or i should create a new wcf service?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before at [Exclude property on WCF DataContract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423405/exclude-property-on-wcf-datacontract)

The answer: no, it violates the contract defined on the class decorated with the `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes.